# My cookie disappears

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, cookies, persistence

I'll try to explain it as easy as possible.

#### Replication:

I'm doing an **auth/login** system where:

1. The user input him credentials and send the data to the server [**classic form**].
2. The server check everything and then (if it's ok) set up a session in the server and response an **static view** which is rendered using handlebars and by **passing one variable**: `sessionName`.
3. This view includes a **js snipet** which **add a cookie** using the code below: `document.cookie += ';session_name={{ sessionName }}'`. At this moment, **all is still correct**. And the **cookie is added** correctly.
4. And then it **redirects** to the root of the website. At this point, **I expect to have the cookie I set before. But there's not.**

#### Relevant data:

- The variable **sessionName** is compiled **properly**.
- The **Analytics** [Mixpanel and Google Analytics] **cookies** are **persistent.**
- I **tested** in **Chrome 39** and **Firefox Developers Edition** using **Mac OSX Yosemite**.
- The **server** uses **node.js** and **hapi.js** of Wallmart Labs with the hapi.js plugin **hapi-auth-cookie**
- I also **tested** to **set the cookie manually** but it doesn't persists neither. Any kind of the ones that I use.
- The **cookie is a simple string**; accurately: *hubato* so: `;session_name=huabto`.

#### TL;DR

My cookies doesn't persist when navigating. Regardless how or what I set in the cookie.

Comment: You mean after redirection, the BROWSER doesn't set the cookie on the header of request?

Comment: And are the (sub)domain and protocols(http, https) the same?

Comment: And on #3 how do you confirm the cookie is correct?

Comment: Are you using different subdomains?

Comment: Ok guys @HiroakiMachida @benjaminjosephw . First thank you for take your time for help me ;) I try to answer all: 1. Where can I check properly these header of request? 2. The subdomains (without, neither www) and protocols (unsafe) are the same all time. 3. I'm printing `document.cookie`, is this enough? Hope it helps!

Comment: Also I realize now that if I create a cookie before the step 1 (send the form) this one will persist as expected.

Comment: so, is it solved? For 1, check here https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#cookies For 3, check here (that's not enough) https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#cookies

Comment: And I don't know about node.js, but I suppose the simplest and most common way to set cookies is to set it on back-end, which mean including Set-Cookie header on Response Headers.

Comment: @HiroakiMachida Guys! I found the error after a loooong time testing. I added the `path=/` to the cookie and works like a charm! Thank you all dudes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add the `path=/` parameter and it works like a charm!
You can find all the information related to the cookies [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265).
And beware of the characters you're using because not all of them are allowed.

Comment: what value did you exactly put on the path atribute? I just have "/" but suddenly my cookie dissapear.

Comment: As per said at: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-5.2.4 The cookie path attributes shall match the location path attribute. In the case of `/` is matching root, therefore the rest of routes. Check the action domain of your cookies and/or the possible subdomain conflicts.